# Regex to get grouping of url

Tags: regex

If I have a URL contstruct

/SomePart/#/Group1/Group2

I need to return the group1 and/or group2, i.e. the url could be either
/SomePart/#/Group1
OR
/SomePart/#/Group1/Group2

The current regex I have only gets the first part, not sure how to extend to the latter.

```
SomePart\/\#\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)
```

Comment: Which language are you using? Many have built in Url processing methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to use a regex? Often using a regular expression is overkill. A few lines of code will be faster, and more maintainable than a big regular expression.

If your language has a split method just use that and check the last two items in the generated array.

```
arr = url.split("/")
if arr[len-2] == "#":
  # There is only one group, so return arr[len-1]
else:
  # Return the last two elements of the array as Group1 and Group2
```

This pseudo-code is probably a good starting place. In parting, an applicable quote:

> "Debugging is twice as hard as writing
>   the code in the first place.
>   Therefore, if you write the code as
>   cleverly as possible, you are, by
>   definition, not smart enough to debug
>   it." --Brian Kernighan

Save your cleverness for something else :)